# Invertible indempotent matrix not equal to identity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, idempotents

On Wikipedia, I found  that the only non-singular idempotent matrix is $\mathrm{\mathbf{I}}$. However, the following matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$

is invertible and is equal to itself when squared. What is it that I am misunderstanding?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Are you working with Boolean matrices? Otherwise this matrix is not idempotent...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A^2= A$, and $A$ is invertible, then we can multiply both sides by the inverse of $A$, and we get $A=I$. That reasoning seems rock solid, to me.

Are you sure that the matrix you showed is both idempotent and invertible?

Comment: oops. I just realized it's not indempotent, sorry.